# VS Code Extension for older version

Tags: visual-studio-code, vsix, azure-data-studio

I want to install an extension on a server without access to the internet, so I downloaded the vsix file and tried to install it on the server. Turns out that the VS code on the server is an old version, 1.59 if I remember correctly.

How can I find the vsix version that can be installed on a particular VS Code version.

I have been looking at the Github page for the extension but not an easy task to match extension version to VS Code version.

Comment: Why not download the latest version of VS Code too? You say it has no internet, but you can clearly download files and get them to the boat somehow, or you wouldn't have been able to get the vsix file to it. 1.59 came out in July 2021.

Comment: look at the history of the `package.json` file and find the VSC version needed that still allows your VSC version